# Алгоритм, строящий путь по всем нужным точкам в матрице?

Tags: алгоритм, матрицы

У меня есть матрица заполненая нулями и единицами. Мне нужно из заданной позиции попытаться построить путь со следующими критериями:

1. Соединяет все нули в матрице
2. Не имеет пересечений с самим собой
3. Не затрагивает единицы

Ну типа Гамильтонов путь.
Каким образом я могу это организовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
Я - невежда в алгоритмах, сильно не пинайте, если че не так :)

Comment: Матрица-то большая? а то лучше ветвлений с отсечениями что-то ничего не придумывается...

Comment: Путь может идти по диагонали? Можете пример показать на маленькой матрице?

Comment: И еще, требуется наидлиннейший такой путь или любой подойдет?

Comment: Подразумевается, что ходить можно только к соседним клеточкам?

Comment: Матрица не больше 8*8.
Прикрепил картинку для наглядности.

Comment: Кроме ветвлений можно использовать метод ветвей и границ, поиск в глубину и прочие из этой бочки. Что вряд ли упростит решение.

Comment: Тогда, думаю, ветвление с отсечениями вполне пройдет.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что кружочки - это нули, а квадраты - это единицы. Но вот в последней строке третий кружок - белый. Я понимаю, что его невозможно захватить с такими условиями. Так вопрос, необходимо включить все нули или нет? Или допустим, если какой-то ноль невозможно включить, то оставить его?

Comment: Если нужно соединить все нули в матрице, то зачем нужно условие «из заданной позиции».

Comment: @AlexanderVeselov, не, белая точка - это как раз последня точка в пути,    она разумеется входит в решение, её недоотметили, так сказать. Кривой скриншот просто.

Comment: @defaultlocale, по условию задачи надо попытаться построить путь из конкретной точки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой вариант решения написанный на С++. Насчет скорости работы на больших массивах не уверен.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector <bool> Visited(1000);
vector <int> Path;
bool s[64][64];
int free_N=0;
int n, m;
bool hamilton(int curr, int end)
{
    Path.push_back(curr); //добавить текущую вершину графа в список
    if (Path.size() == free_N  && curr == end)
    {
        //если размер пути равен количеству нулей и текущая (последняя) 
        //вершина является той, путь к которой мы ищем, то конец. Решение построено
        return true;
    }
    //в эту часть заходит, если решение ещё не найдено
    Visited[curr] = true; //помечаем текущую вершину посещенной
    for (int next = 0; next < n*m; ++next)
        //далее ищем следующую вершину
        if (s[curr][next] == 1 && !Visited[next])
            //если вершина смежна с текущей и она ещё не посещена,
            //то вызываем этот же алгоритм рекурсивно для поиска следующей вершины
            if (hamilton(next,end))
                //если функция вернула true, то путь уже найден. И вернется
                //true для всех остальных веток рекурсии
                return true;
    Visited[curr] = false;
    //иначе, выбранная вершина была ошибочная, удаляем её из пути
    //и помечаем не посещенной
    Path.pop_back();
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2; //ввод начальной и конечной точки
    int begin = x1*m+y1, end = x2*m+y2;
    bool in[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) cin >> in[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < m*n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m*n; j++)
        {
            s[i][j] = 0;
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //построение матрицы смежности
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (in[i][j]) continue;
            free_N++;
            if (i + 1 < n && in[i + 1][j] == 0)
            {
                s[(i + 1)*m + j][i*m + j] = 1;
                s[i*m + j][(i + 1)*m + j] = 1;
            }
            if (j + 1 < m && in[i][j + 1] == 0)
            {
                s[i*m + j + 1][i*m + j] = 1;
                s[i*m + j][i*m + j + 1] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    hamilton(begin, end); //сам алгоритм
    cout << "Path: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < Path.size(); i++) cout << "[" << Path[i] / m << "][" << Path[i] % m << "] " << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Ваш пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто, спасибо. Можешь только еще добавить немного комментариев в функции  hamilton?

Comment: Добавил описание о ответ. Если ответ удовлетворил ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, пометьте его как решение.

Comment: Всё ясно-понятно. Благодарствую.

Comment: Если хотите наглядно посмотреть, как работает алгоритм, напишите строку for (int i = 0; i < Path.size(); i++) cout << "[" << Path[i] / m << "][" << Path[i] % m << "] "; cout << endl; в начало функции hamilton.

Comment: @Pasha есть какие-то другие алгоритмы или улучшения для данного алгоритма? Текущий алгоритм хорош, но на небольших размерах матрицы, например на матрице 10х10 работает слишком долго.