# Ориентирование графа

Tags: алгоритм, графы, олимпиада

Допустим есть неориентированный граф, и заданы точки старта и финиша. Нужно ориентировать его ребра так что б получить граф без циклов, в котором из точки старта можно дойти до точки финиша и через каждое ребро существует минимум один путь. Конечные точки задаются корректно, и ответ точно существует. Подскажите алгоритм пожалуйста

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что можно применить поиск в ширину, при этом ориентируя ребра из текущей вершины в соседние, только не останавливаясь, дойдя до финиша, а продолжая работу, пока все ребра не будут обойдены.

Comment: может быть такой граф по которому невозможно сделать так что бы через каждую вершину лежал минимум один путь. пример граф из трёх точек 1-2-3 последовательно соединённых. при этом начальная 1, а конечная 2.

Comment: конечные точки задаются корректно, и ответ точно существует

Comment: Кажется, это вам подойдет [Похожая задача](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709193/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5/709303#709303)